# Wordpress revision error 404

Tags: php, wordpress

I get post revision link form Wordpress database and when I click on this link I get 404 error. Someone know what happened?

It's my link on localhost:

```
http://localhost/27-revision-3/
```

I get my template menu and everything but 404 error is showed.

Comment: perhaps that directory doesn't exist? Why do you think it should?

Comment: this link is in database, why wordpress save something like that ? How I can get revision link from db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

revisions didn't publish so we can't view those.

If you want to select that which revision would be shown use [Revision Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/revision-control/)

Comment: I only need link to wp-admin where I can see this revison.

Comment: manually you can find this post, in database in field guid you must follow nearest p number to this revision that its post type is post